# Keywords for classification of 2D time series data?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, time-series-analysis

Trying to find the right search terms for literature on classifying 2D time series data.

I am looking at data from positional tracking of a swarm of insects over time. I have example datasets for specific insect behaviors, and I would like to play around with training a classifier on these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in [RNNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network) (e.g., LSTMs) or [Hidden Markov models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model).  RNNs can be used directly for classification.  HMMs can be used to build a generative model for each class, which can then be used for classification: if $x$ is the observed 2D time series, the model for class $c$ lets you compute $P(x|c)$, and then you can classify $x$ by selecting the class $c$ that maximizes $P(x|c)$ (the maximum likelihood principle).

Comment: HMMs are the approach I ended up going with. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

The one-nearest neighbor classifier is very competitive for time series.
http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/ICML2006.pdf
If you want code or data, I have lots of both.
eamonn